# How can I update a multi-key hash item in redis?

Tags: javascript, redis, ioredis

I have a collection of `Providers`.
Each provider can have multiple `Orders`.

I need to save in redis the Order ids related to each provider in json array.

One possible solution is to use HSET.

```
HSET provider_orders providerId:1 "['1234']"
```

or in javascript:

```
ioredis.hset(
    'provider_orders',
    `providerId:1`,
    ['1234'],
  )
```

Where `1` is the provider id and `'1234'` is the orderId

However, if I need to add a new order to the same provider I would need to get the current order ids array and add the new order id.

Something like this:

```
const currentOrders = ioredis.hget(
        'provider_orders',
        `providerId:${deliverer.id}`
      )
currentOrders.push(newOrder)
ioredis.hset(
        'provider_orders',
        `providerId:${deliverer.id}`,
        currentOrders,
      )
```

Is this the best way to do something like that?

Another option I have considered is to create new keys for each provider and use SADD.

```
SADD provider:order:1 "1234"
```

Where `1` is the provider id and `'1234'` is the orderId

However, this would create a lot of keys. One for each provider.

Comment: Is "many keys" really an issue? How many providers do you have? Does the number grow fast? What is the expected TTL of an order? The key is removed once the last set member is removed so there won't be any "empty" sets left.

Comment: @OndřejXichtSvětlík Provider numbers can grow over time (~3000 in 3 years). It doesn't grow fast but it may be a problem later. The expected TTL is 1 day. Removing the key when the orders are empty sounds like a good idea. Do you recommend doing this?

Comment: You don't actually need to remove the key, it's done automatically by Redis once the set is empty. And yes, if you wish to use redis for this, I'd do it exactly this way. How many orders do you expect to have "in process" simultaneously? For how many providers? That's the number of keys/members stored in Redis.

Comment: I expect to have around 20 orders in process. And around 200 simultaneously (it can grow over time).

Comment: Then go for it, these are no big numbers, easilly manageable even manually. Good luck.